# Data normalization for lme mixed model_R

Tags: r, mixed-model, data-transformation, residuals

I have a set of data and I am going to apply the **lme mixed model**.
However, the data are not normally distributed (see the graph below).

[image].

I tried (log, sqrt, zscore) and box-cox transformations and even the graphs look better, Kolmogorov-Smirnov test gave me a max p-value=0.008.

The residual plot for the lme model (used data were transformed with box-cox) is attached below and

*Lilliefors (Kolmogorov-Smirnov) normality test
p-value = 9.909e-12*
[image]

To my knowledge, the residuals plot should not have any pattern and I can not see any on my plot, but why the normality tests (Kolmogorov-Smirnov / Shapiro) gave me values <0.05?

My question is:

What also can I do to normalize my data and use them for mixed model (lme)?

Comment: (if OP is still around ...) is the density plot based on the *residuals* or on the *response variable*?

Answer (score 1):

A few points of general advice:

1) The plot you have of residuals vs. index isn't particularly useful for assessing the normality of the residuals.  It is more useful to use a q-q plot or a histogram.

2) Don't rely on statistical tests (Shapiro-Wilk, Anderson–Darling, Kolmogorov–Smirnov, et al.) to determine if data or residuals are normally-distributed.  They are sensitive to sample size.  If you have a lot of data, they are likely to find a significant deviation from normal even if that deviation is small.

Here is a small example of a q-q plot and histogram in R.  The chosen transformation doesn't work all that well for this example.

```
library(nlme)

data(mtcars)

mtcars$mpg_trans = mtcars$mpg ^ 1.3 

model = lme(mpg_trans ~ disp + cyl, random=~1|gear,
            data=mtcars,
            method="REML")

x = residuals(model)

hist(x, prob=TRUE, col="darkgray")
Range = seq(min(x), max(x), length = length(x))
Norm = dnorm(Range, mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))
lines(Range, Norm, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

```
qqnorm(x)
qqline(x, col="red")
```

[image]

```
plot(predict(model), residuals(model))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply [the Johnson transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson's_SU-distribution) to normalize a data.

```
# require
library(Johnson)
#Applying Johnson transformation 
your_data_JT<-RE.Johnson(your_data)
# check p-value of the Anderson-Darling test
your_data_JT$p
```